# Search Map with Google Map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

everyone

i have a problem with my project

here is my search.java code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Search extends Activity {

   TextView error,br2;
   Spinner namjal2;
   String i,returnString2,jln;
   String[] jalan = {"A.Yani", "Ambengan", "Anjasmoro","Baliwerti","Basuki Rahmat","Bintoro","Ciliwung","Citarum","Citandui","Darmo Daya","Darmokali","Dharmawangsa","Dinoyo","Embong Kemiri","Embong Malang"};


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        br2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.berita2);
        namjal2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.namjalSearch);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jalan);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         namjal2.setAdapter(aa);




   }

   public void clickHandler(View view){
    Intent a = null;
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.find:
        jln = jalan[namjal2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_jalan", jln));


/*            String valid = "1";*/      

        String response = null;

        try {

           response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/android/searchInfo.php", postParameters);


           String result = response.toString();  
           //parse json data

              try{
                      returnString2 = "";


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                              JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                              Log.i("log_tag","id_kepadatan: "+json_data.getInt("id_kepadatan")+
                                      ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                      ", nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                                      ", status: "+json_data.getString("status")+
                                      ", tanggal: "+json_data.getString("tanggal")+
                                      ", waktu: "+json_data.getString("waktu")+
                                      ", keterangan: "+json_data.getString("keterangan")
                              );
                              if(result.equals(null)){
                              //Get an output to the screen
                             returnString2 += "Data tidak ada";
                              }
                              else{
                              returnString2 += "\n" + json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + " mengalami "+ json_data.getString("status")+ " pada "+ json_data.getString("tanggal")+ " waktu "+ json_data.getString("waktu")+ " karena "+ json_data.getString("keterangan");
                              }
                      }
              }


              catch(JSONException e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
              }

              try{


               br2.setText(returnString2);


              }


              catch(Exception e){

               Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          

              }   

         }

               catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     

         }
        break;

   case R.id.back:
        a = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
}
   }


}
```

and here is my search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:background="#ffffff"  
   > 

  <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          >
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="PENCARIAN BERITA TERBARU"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Masukkan Nama Jalan"/>

          <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/namjalSearch" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/find" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dip"
                android:text="Find"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"/>
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/berita2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                />  
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textBack" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="190dip"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="BACK"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="125dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="258dip"
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:background="@null" 
                android:onClick="clickHandler"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/cariPeta" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="125dip"
                android:text="Cari Peta"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my goal is when i click the "cariPeta" button, it will show the map from the street which choosen

for example, if spinner pointing one name of the street (ex : "A.Yani" street) ... then,  when i click "cariPeta" button,,,it will show the map of "A.Yani" street in google map

my problem is, i dont know what code should i write....can you tell me? i will much appreciate it because this project is very important to me

Thank You.....

Comment: Please narrow your question. What is your problem? For example :
**1.** get Place name from spinner.
**2.** convert Place name to long/lat...
**3.** center mapView to your Place's position....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let me guide you.
You need to write click event of button.
On click of that button getSelectedIndex of spinner (there is a readymade method for it in spinner obj).

After receiving index value fetch text from string array.

Then Map will come in picture. But to deal with the map you need pair of lat/long.

Using lat/long you can show any point on map.

Comment: how can i find long/lat if the address is just a name (A.Yani street)? is there a code to convert address (example : A.Yani) to long/lat so Google Map can find it? can you please tell me the code? Thank You

Comment: Yes there is a way to get address from lat/lng. In android its called reverse geo coding.http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android Try this link. Ut has 100% working code at bottom.